# how to not repeat yourself with similar model objects in django

Tags: django, django-models, dry

I have 2 objects object1 and object2 in two different apps (app1 and app2). Object1 has a 1 to many relationship with Object2.  Each object has a settings model object.

The settings are identical except each has a one to one relationship to their respective object.

Is this repeating myself if the two objects have their own settings or should they share a settings object?

The structure currently looks like:

```
class Object1(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Object2(models.Model):
        object1 = models.ForeignKey(Object1)



#This is in app 1
class Setting(models.Model):
    object1 = models.OneToOneField(Object1)
    setting_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

#This is in app 2
class Setting(models.Model):
    object2 = models.OneToOneField(Object2)
    setting_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want an abstract base class.

```
class SettingBase(models.Model):
    setting_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Setting1(SettingBase):
    object1 = models.OneToOneField(Object1)

class Setting2(SettingBase):
    object2 = models.OneToOneField(Object2)
```